# Why is this series summable?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, limits-and-convergence

Let $\delta, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, $\delta >0$, $\epsilon >0$.
Let $\{ a_k\}^\infty$,$\{ b_k\}^\infty$ be sequences of positive integers such that

$\lim \sup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{ (\prod^k a_j)^{2 +2/\epsilon + \delta}} \frac{1}{b_{k+1}} = \infty$ and for every suf. large $k$ we have
$\sqrt[1+\epsilon]{ \frac{a_{k+1}}{b_{k+1}} }\geq \sqrt[1+\epsilon]{ \frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}} }+1$.
Why is the infinite series $\sum^\infty \frac{b_k}{a_k}$  summable?
(This claim comes from a theorem in a published paper whose proof we are formalising using the proof assistant Isabelle/HOL. Summability easily follows if we strengthen the assumption substituting $\lim \sup$ with $\lim$, but is there a way to show summability without strengthening any assumption?) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The condition that for all large enough $k$ we have
$\sqrt[1+\epsilon]{ \frac{a_{k+1}}{b_{k+1}} }\geq \sqrt[1+\epsilon]{ \frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}} }+1$ implies that $\sqrt[1+\epsilon]{ \frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}} }>k-c$  and hence $\frac{b_{k}}{a_{k}}<\frac1{(k-c)^{1+\epsilon}}$ for some real $c>0$ and all large enough $k>c$, which yields the convergence of series $\sum^\infty \frac{b_k}{a_k}$.

(The condition 
$\lim \sup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{ (\prod^k a_j)^{2 +2/\epsilon + \delta}} \frac{1}{b_{k+1}} = \infty$ is not needed here.)

Comment: Dear Iosif, many thanks - of course your hint will be acknowledged in our code of the formal proof!